# Create web3 signature

Tags: javascript, ethereum, web3js, sign, metamask

I'm trying to connect metamask to third-party website using web3.js
So I need to sign signature which containts address and nonce
The problem is i can't get the same signature as by manual metamask with browser
I think I can't understand how exactly the signature is built
Any idead, how i can do that?

metamasak message

[image: 1]

```
message = {
        address: '0xf82Fa3FC08087a1837d5374172F881C2bF74db36',
        nonce: '0xc1fb834b1bdb671d20df6fe6ca3e8fdde2a8d424acb1c69510e56d2ff9a56aee'
    }
    let signature = web3.eth.accounts.sign(message, privateKey).signature;
```

Comment: I've also tried using await web3.utils.soliditySha3(message.address, message.nonce); but signature is still different

Comment: For such use cases it is better to use ready-made [Sign in with Ethereum packages](https://login.xyz/)

Comment: @MikkoOhtamaa even there signing look quite normal, but in my case the notification with message looks different, like, it has different text style and design, I think its the main problem, maybe there is another ver, or smth like that